# Not Readable Firebase Database

Tags: php, firebase

I have Project/User/Admin/dashboard.php, now i include the the dbconfig inside only of Project and the JSON file/Private key. Now on my dashboard i'm receiving an error saying

"Fatal error: Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: The file at '/-----------.json' is not readable in ....."

here is my dbcon.php

```
<?php

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use Kreait\Firebase\Factory;

$factory = (new Factory)
    ->withServiceAccount('/soilution-e35c1-firebase-adminsdk-m2elw-574c063fb3.json')
    ->withDatabaseUri('https://soilution-e35c1-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/');

    $database = $factory->createDatabase();
?>
```

i tried using **DIR** but still not working. i can't use the file dbcon on other folder, i change location and same thing the error keeps on coming. but i can create data and update on database.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to load the config file from the root directory with this code:

```
->withServiceAccount('/soilution-e35c1-firebase-adminsdk-m2elw-574c063fb3.json')
```

Most likely the file is not in the root directory, but in the same directory as the PHP script. In that case, try either:

```
->withServiceAccount('./soilution-e35c1-firebase-adminsdk-m2elw-574c063fb3.json')
```

Or:

```
->withServiceAccount('soilution-e35c1-firebase-adminsdk-m2elw-574c063fb3.json')
```

Comment: i remove the / but same thing. i added a line of code that will check if the db is not exist or readable. theres no error, I'm trying to use the dbcon.php inside of users/admin/ to dashboard.php. the dbcon is perfectly working on the same path of the dbcon on sign in and sign up page. but on dashboard.php saying its not readable.